# Laravel - Placing only folder public in web root gives only a blank screen

Tags: laravel-5

I've tried to experiment with placing only the public folder in the web root and all other folders and files outside the web root. I've done this by following the article on Laravel News: https://laravel-news.com/subfolder-install.

In index.php I've changed the two paths to:

```
require DIR.'/data/sites/web/domainname/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once DIR.'/data/sites/web/domainname/laravel/blog/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But then I only get a white screen when I approach https://domainname/public.

The server web root is: data/sites/web/domainname/www/..

When I place the whole app in the web root (with a .htaccessfile for security) the url is: https://domainname/laravel/blog/public

I've tried also the following option in index.php:

```
require DIR.'/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once DIR.'/../../laravel/blog/bootstrap/app.php';
```

But this also gives a white screen.

Is there something that I've done wrong or have forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

Question is solved, see this post on Laracasts:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-placing-only-folder-public-in-web-root